# Is there a difference between "is visible" and "click element" in Robot Framework/Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

These two lines don't work as expected:

```
wait until element is visible  ${my xpath}
SeleniumLibrary.click element  ${my xpath}
```

Approximately half of the time the second line fails. I am not in front of my computer now but it either fails with *stale element* or *couldn't find element with id...*.

If I add a `sleep  3` or so inbetween the lines the second line never fails.

These two lines work frequently but they also fail frequently. Is there a difference in how RF detects that something is visible and how Selenium sends a click to the same element?

Comment: Given that you are reporting a stale element, that means that something you are doing in previous lines is refreshing the entire or at least part of the page that holds the element you are trying to click. Deal with the page refresh first, then this code will work fine.

Comment: The premise of your question is strangely worded... surely you understand that `is visible` is a test to see if an element is in fact visible and `click element` performs the click action on the given element so there clearly is a well-defined difference between the two. You should probably reword this to make it more clear what you are actually asking.

Comment: @JeffC Is it? I first wait for an element to be visible so I can click it. When I read the docs _wait_ seems more conservative than _click_ so if an element fulfills the requirements by wait it most definitely should be clickable.

Comment: If that were true, there wouldn't be a wait for visible AND a wait for clickable... at least in Selenium C#, Java, and python.

Comment: @EmLi Can you point to the documentation that introduces the "is visibile" keyword(s) in Robot.  Perhaps there is a similar "is clickable".

Comment: @JohnChesshir http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Wait%20Until%20Element%20Is%20Visible I have also tried `wait until enabled` with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can include a custom timeout in the first keyword instead of using sleep.

```
Wait Until Element Is Visible  ${my xpath}  3 seconds
Click Element                  ${my xpath}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question in short no there is no difference between how RF detects that something is visible and how selenium sends a click to that same element. I looked at the source code for Selenium and both functions use the same locator argument.

```
@keyword
    def click_element(self, locator, modifier=False, action_chain=False):
```

and

```
@keyword
    def wait_until_element_is_visible(self, locator, timeout=None, error=None):
```

A keyword instead I would suggest is

```
wait until page contains element    ${my xpath}
```

This allows for the web page to be fully loaded before looking for the element.